# I get error when download open_file plugin to my App

Tags: flutter, dart

i got this error:

Note: C:\Users\mohammed\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\open_file-3.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\crazecoder\openfile\OpenFilePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

my pubspec.yaml

```
name: mohaseb
```

description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: '>=3.0.2 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
shared_preferences: ^2.1.1
pdf: ^3.10.4
path_provider: ^2.0.15
open_file: ^3.3.2

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

```
flutter:
```

uses-material-design: true

and here my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<application
    android:label="mohaseb"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

i run codes
flutter pub add open_file

and i have added to my pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
path_provider: ^2.0.15

Comment: Not related to this issue but don't use open_file plugin. When you release your app Google Play Store will reject it because open_file contains permission (REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGE) that are not allowed. Instead, use open_file_safe.

Comment: Related to this issue, that is not an error, it's a warning and can be ignored.

Comment: I know this is a warning, but it makes my app not work and even the icons appear unfamiliar